# Finding the nearest multiple of a number to another number - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an integer which is the length of a text field, lets say the length is 6. I need to find the nearest multiple of 16 to this number and then get the difference between the two numbers. So in this case it would be 8 (It could also be 4 but I'm only interested in going up).

I have an implementation of this in C#:

```
int padding = 16 - (txtUserPwd.TextLength % 16);
```

However I can't work out how to do this in Objective-C (especially without RoundUp).

It's probably quite simple to do but I can't work it out, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Exactly how you did it in C#, if that really is your whole C# code. With the exception of `txtUserPwd.TextLength`, it's all valid Obj C.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the exact same code except for `length` to get the length of the string?

Comment: Did you try this code? because it will work lol.

Comment: Are you just trying to add some characters after the input to make the final length equal 16?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(int)differenceToNextPowerOfTwo:(int)n
{
    unsigned int v = n;
    v--;
    v |= v >> 1;
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v |= v >> 16;
    v++;
    return v - n;
}
```

Source: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2